# How to simulate mouse clicks as fast as possible in Java?

Tags: java, mouse, race-condition, awtrobot

I'm simulating mouse clicks and I want to do it as fast as possible.

Currently I'm using the Robot class with this:

```
private static int milliSecondClickDelay = 25;

public static void leftClickMouse(){
    Main.robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Main.robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Main.robot.delay(milliSecondClickDelay);
    Main.robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
}
```

Unfortunately I have to use delay, or else I get a race condition where the mouse moves before the release is registered.

25 is the lowest delay I can use without encountering this problem, but the task I'm doing takes 14 seconds with this. I've gotten down to 6 seconds with a 5 millisecond delay, but then the result is horribly inconsistent.

Can I simulate clicks another way?

Thanks in advance.

update:

I've updated the function to this:

```
public static synchronized void leftClickMouse(){
    Main.robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Main.robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Main.robot.waitForIdle();
    Main.robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
}
```

the Robot.waitForIdle() waits until all events currently on the event queue have been processed, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I suppose that you could use native code to queue mouse click messages on the OS's system message queue. I haven't the foggiest idea of how to do this in my own OS, Windows, much less all the others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your application is acting on a non java application.  You are probably stuck with setting delays.

If this is being done in a java application itself to interact with itself, you could use SwingUtilies and add each robot action to the AWT thread.  This will probably allow for the mouse pressed/released events to be processed by your application.

I guess we need more info.  What is your application interacting with?  If it is not the application itself, you are probably stuck with adding delays in.  I'd get it working then increase delays by atleast 20% as a safety factor.  I'd actually see what works consistently and double the delays.

Depending on what you are doing, you could try setting the priority of the target application to realtime and the java application to the lowest priority in task manager.  It might help a bit but it doesn't resolve the problem.